# XMLTABLE get location to the variables

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, xmltable

maybe someone can see the problem have this query :

```
    select application_id, response_body, xx.*
from(
select application_id, 
response_body
from stage_lt.cb_data_execution_entry_details deed, stage_lt.cb_data_execution_entry dee , stage_lt.cb_application_to_execution_entry aee
where deed.execution_entry_id=dee.id and aee.execution_entry_id=deed.execution_entry_id  and dee.provider_name='cb'
and application_id = '2253545'
limit 1) x
cross join xmltable (
             '/BatchResponse/Commands/Command/GenericReport/Data/ExistingContracts/Contract' 
              passing cast(x.response_body as xml)
              columns
                contract_key int path '@key',
                amountr numeric path 'OutstandingAmountR',
                average_amount numeric path 'AverageMonthlyInstalmentAmount') as xx
```

But this query get blanks for me

here is full direction to my results from xml tree

`/responseContainer/ns2:Report/ns2:Registers/ns2:PositiveInfo/BatchResponse/Commands/Command/GenericReport/Data/ExistingContracts/Contract`

Here is my full XML [XMLTREE](https://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer/y22fbb8e2)

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/L2nmRe16?hide=2)

my desired results to grooup by `Contract key` all application_id :

| ID | Contract key | OutstandingAmountR | AverageMonthlyInstalmentAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2253545 | 1 | 12320.84 | 224.15 |
| 2253545 | 9 | 3914.13 | 74.96 |
| 2253545 | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query abd make a [mre], without sample data, it is quite hard tu guess

Comment: edited, added fiddle